# Erro ao usar o método split()

Tags: javascript

Estou resolvendo um problema onde tenho de pegar o primeiro e o último nome de uma pessoa e devo retornar as iniciais da mesma. Como sou iniciante na área, certamente que existem outras maneiras de resolver essa questão. Independente das outras maneiras, gostaria de entender o que fiz de errado, erro que recebo:

> Uncaught TypeError: firstName.split is not a function at pickInitials (script.js:18)              at script.js:24

na solução que tentei abaixo:

```js
     const pickInitials = function (name) {
    
      const NameArray = name.split(' '); // Convertendo string recebida para array com dois elementos
      
      const firstName = []; // Criando outras arrays para armazenar elementos da conversão anterior
      const lastName = [];
    
      firstName.push(NameArray[0]); // Adicionando primeiro e segundo nome nas arrays criadas
      lastName.push(NameArray[1]);
    
      const firstNameArray = firstName.split(''); // Dividindo arrays criadas em outras arrays, agora por caractere, aqui ocorre o erro
      const lastNameArray = lastName.split('');
    
      return console.log(`${firstNameArray[0]}.${lastNameArray[0]}`); // Retornando primeiro caractere de cada array
    }
    
    pickInitials('Diego Oliveira');
    pickInitials('Sam Harris');
    pickInitials('Patrick Feeney');
```

Comment: nesse caso, se eu entendi bem o código, deveria ser: `const firstNameArray = firstName[0].split('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não seria `firstName[0].split('');` em vez de `firstName.split('');` e `lastName[0].split('');` em vez de `lastName.split('');`, para este caso?

Desta forma:

```js
     const pickInitials = function (name) {
    
      const NameArray = name.split(' '); // Convertendo string recebida para array com dois elementos
      
      const firstName = []; // Criando outras arrays para armazenar elementos da conversão anterior
      const lastName = [];
    
      firstName.push(NameArray[0]); // Adicionando primeiro e segundo nome nas arrays criadas
      lastName.push(NameArray[1]);
    
      const firstNameArray = firstName[0].split(''); // Dividindo arrays criadas em outras arrays, agora por caractere, aqui ocorre o erro
      const lastNameArray = lastName[0].split('');
    
      return console.log(`${firstNameArray[0]}.${lastNameArray[0]}`); // Retornando primeiro caractere de cada array
    }
    
    pickInitials('Diego Oliveira');
    pickInitials('Sam Harris');
    pickInitials('Patrick Feeney');
```

Acontece que aqui `firstName.push(NameArray[0]);` você adicionou um elemento ao array `firstName`, logo para acessar este elemento que está no index `0`, você precisa do `[0]` antes do método `.split('')`. O mesmo vale para o array `lastName`.

O erro se deve ao fato de que `split` é um método de string e não de array.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vi que fez algumas correções à minha pergunta e eu agradeço, cheguei agora e tô meio perdido, rs